# Getting 2 records in the result while inserting data into redshift table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert data in `redshift` table its inserting 2 records every time.

```
Table: create table venue(
    venueid smallint not null distkey sortkey,
    venuename varchar(100),
    venuecity varchar(30),
    venuestate char(2),
    venueseats integer);
Query: Insert into venue(venueid,venuename,venuecity,venuestate,venueseats) 
       values (2,'mno','pqrs','tu',000);
```

output:

```
venueid venuename   venuecity   venuestate  venueseats
2   mno           pqrs              tu             2000
2   mno           pqrs              tu             2000
```

please suggest me..

Comment: If i run that code on redshift - of course I get only 1 row. please can you expand your question to include your log output including one final command "select * from venue;"

Comment: @tejaswi Perhaps you ran the `INSERT` command twice? That would result in two identical rows.

Comment: @JonScott : After table got create i have inserted one record into the table and i tried select query "select * from venue;" then its shows the result like     
 output:

venueid venuename   venuecity   venuestate  venueseats
2   mno           pqrs              tu             2000
2   mno           pqrs              tu             2000

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: No i ran only once but its getting 2 records in the result

Comment: This should not be happening. Try dropping the table and running the commands again (`DROP TABLE venue`) or simply empty the table (`TRUNCATE venue`) and run the `INSERT` again.